# Idiomatic way to read a binary file with Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm learning Kotlin and need to read a large binary file with carriage return (0x0d) block delimiters.

Is there a more idiomatic method for this example in Kotlin?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val bis = File(args[0]).inputStream().buffered()
    val buf = ArrayList<Int>()
    while(true) {
        val i = bis.read()
        if (i < 0) break
        buf.add(i)
        if (i == 0x0d) {
            process(buf)
            buf.clear() 
        }
    }
    bis.close()
}
```

Comment: [`readBytes`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/read-bytes.html)?

Comment: As far as idiom is concerned, should use `bis.use { ... }`, which is the equivalent of Java's try-with-resources. However, I'm more worried by your usage of `ArrayList<Int>` as a buffer, it's hugely wasteful.

Comment: You could use [`sequence`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/sequence.html) with your `while (true)` loop and [`yield`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/-sequence-scope/yield.html) to return your buffers lazily. Then do `sequence { /* ... */ }.forEach { process(it) }`.